# How to restart calculation in Quantum ESPRESSO?

Tags: quantum-espresso

I was performing a vc-relax calculation in Quantum ESPRESSO. I have 18 SCF cycles that have been already completed, but my PC just shuts up because of an energy blackout. Is there any form to restart my calculation from some type of *checkpoint*?

I put in my input file the line `restart_mode = "from_scratch"` but I don't know if that is sufficient.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer:

No, using `restart_mode = "from_scratch"` will not work for your purpose. The calculation needs to be started from the beginning.

## Why `restart_mode = "from_scratch"` will not work:

This means that the calculation will be started from the very beginning even if there exists an interrupted earlier calculation. Maybe what you are looking for is `restart_mode = "restart"` which is used to continue previous interrupted run. However, this too will not work in your case since this requires that the previous calculation has been stopped *cleanly*. That means during the run, if you create a file `your_prefix.EXIT` in the `outdir` directory, the calculation terminates but saves the charge density, wavefunction, and other info. But in your case, it was due to power shut down, so the calculation stopped abruptly and the files are almost certainly corrupted. More about the usage of `restart_mode` switch can be found in [here](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html#idm65).

## What you can do now:

You can use these two switches `startingpot="file"` and `startingwfc="file"` in your input file within the `&ELECTRON` namelist. By doing so, the code will not guess an initial charge density and wavefunction from atomic superposition or random guess. Instead the code will try to use the last found charge density and wavefunction from your `outdir` (if it exists). It might give you some time advantages. In any case, the calculation type (spin polarized/unpolarized), the `outdir` and the `prefix` must be the same but you can use different parallelization levels here (you cannot change anything at all in case of `restart_mode="restart"`).

## Caveat:

I cannot guaranty that the above-mentioned suggestion will give you time advantage because it doesn't always work. I am not sure about the reason but sometimes starting from an existing wavefunction takes much more time to converge than the default one takes. My personal experience says that the first iteration of the SCF loop will take longer to converge but rest of them will be a little faster if you use `startingwfc` and `startingpot`.